# Avoid remove record in delete method

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

i need to implement a modify in delete action. Really in my application some records arent removed, only change a property to not show in application.

I think i can implement this in delete metho in datacontext partial class but i don´t know if is posible to cancel the remove action.

```
Private Sub DeleteCITA(instance As CITA)
    instance.Eliminado = True
    'I need cancel remove action
End Sub
```

thanks to all!

Comment: So do not use delete; it is very confusing for future maintenance to intervene in the entire framework

Comment: Did you consider making it using triggers on your SQL tables?

Comment: I think using delete is better cause not in all entities i need this behavior and solving this i use always same method.

Comment: Triggers dont work for me cause i need to register in other table the user and the action

Answer (score 0):

I write an example in C#.

```
    public void DeleteCITA(CITA instance)
    {
        instance.Eliminado = true;
        ObjectStateEntry entry = Context.ObjectStateManger.GetObjectStateEntry(instance);
        entry.SetModified();
    }
```

Context - is your DBContext object

Comment: Sorry @backs but i dont find the way to do this in vb ... i googled and idont know how get dbcontext and testing code i get this

`Dim a As ObjectContext
        Dim value As ObjectStateManager
        value = a.ObjectStateManager`
But value hasnt ChangeObjectState method

Comment: i answer to me... i use framework 3.5 and changeojectstate is from 4.0. I cannot change framework... i have to find other solution